# Boolean attribute not being saved via check_box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, form-helpers

I have a Job model with an attribute of :rush which is a boolean. I used the check_box form helper to toggle :rush.

**The check box form element:**

```
<%= check_box_tag(:rush) %>
<%= label_tag(:rush, "Rush?") %>
```

**My strong parameters method:**

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:recipient, :age, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :weight, :hair, :eyes, :other_info, :instructions, :user_id, :company_id, :case_id, :rush, addresses_attributes:[:id, :label, :addy, :apt, :city, :state, :zip ] )
end
```

**The  Create action:**

```
def create
  @job = Job.new(job_params)
  @job.user_id = current_user.id

  if @job.save
    redirect_to current_user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

When the form is submitted, it doesn't save :rush yet all other attributes including nested attributes save just fine.
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function says:

```
params.require(:job).permit(:recipient, :age, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :weight, :hair, :eyes, :other_info, :instructions, :user_id, :company_id, :case_id, :rush, addresses_attributes:[:id, :label, :addy, :apt, :city, :state, :zip ] )
```

Then you are expecting `:rush` nested inside `:job`, that is, `params[:job][:rush]`. So you should nest it inside the `job` attribute in your html:

```
<%= check_box_tag("job[rush]") %>
```

this should work.

Comment: Any particular reason why this is? Is it just a convention for boolean methods inside of forms? I'm new to rails so any explanation that would help me understand this convention would greatly be appreciated.